# Delay loading records of subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with search fields and then the search results are shown in a subform below the search fields.

By default the subform loads all records prior to any search criteria being entered.

As this database grows the number of possible records to search will get quite large, so I don't really want the subform to load all records before the user attempts to makes a search.

What's the most performance-friendly way of loading the search results subform without showing any of the records to begin with?

I've considered setting the subform recordsource SQL to search for something I know will never be in the results... but I'm thinking that still requires the records to be loaded first and then filtered (might be wrong about this though).

Ideally I'd like the search results subform to load with the field names of the recordset only, but with no records until the user attempts a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the subform's record source to a query which returns a single manufactured row.

```sql
SELECT
    0 AS id,
    '' AS fname,
    '' AS lname,
    '' AS email
```

That will not pull any records from your table.

After you gather the user's search criteria, build the new `SELECT` and assign it as the record source.

Comment: Great idea.. thanks. One fly in the ointment though: I've created a calculated text field in the search results that replaces 2 other fields in the record source (basically concatenates the 2 fields and adds some text). Unfortunately the additional text in the calculated field remains and I'm not sure how to get rid of it. Trying to assign the calculated textbox field to a 0-length string produces an error.

Comment: When you're talking about a calculated field, do you mean the calculation is done in the Control Source of a subform control, or as a field expression in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: It's done in the Control Source of the subform control; specifically: `[ColloquialCourseTitle] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "(LARS: " & [LarsAimTitle] & ")"` Which leaves the text **(LARS: )** in the textbox in the subform. I tried an `iif` statement in the Control Source too, to test if the concatenated fields were 0-length, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: So the text box contains **(LARS: )** initially when the subform contains only the manufactured row.  I'm not sure why that is a problem.  Doesn't it display correctly once you alter the subform record source based on the user's search criteria?

Comment: Since you will be using VBA to alter the record source, I suppose you could also alter the text box Control Source at the same time.  Would that help?  (Sorry if I'm being thick-headed here.)

Comment: Ok, I've managed to change the Control Source to 0-length via VBA, trying to change it back to `[ColloquialCourseTitle] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "(LARS: " & [LarsAimTitle] & ")"` triggers an error though: Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression. No idea where it's getting '|1' from...

Comment: I'm stuck, Matt.  If you upload a copy of the db to a file sharing site and give us a link, I'll have a look.

Comment: I think the issue is that I need to refer to the ControlSource expression within quotes itself. At the moment I have `Me.[tblProspectus_Search]![txtCourseCalc].ControlSource = [ColloquialCourseTitle] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "(LARS: " & [LarsAimTitle] & ")"`, but i'm pretty sure the expression should start `"=`. I'm no good at working out these quotes within quotes expressions though... going to have a look around the internet for a bit. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Slowly built it up and this seems to work: `"=[ColloquialCourseTitle]& Chr(13) & Chr(10)&""(LARS: ""&[LarsAimTitle]&"")"""` Thanks again for your help.